# How to underline a given title and make it wrap automatically according to the fixed width?

Tags: wrap

How to unline a given title and make the title wrap automatically according to the fixed width,  I
know I need to use the packages

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{CJKulem}
```

and use it like this

```
\uline{This a very long title just for demonstration so how to make it  wrap automatically according to the fixed width}
```

It can warp automatically, but it fills the whole line of the page, I just want it warps according to fixed width such as 300pt, how can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: You could put the text into a `minipage` or `\parbox` with the desired width, but why are you referring to the text as "title"?

Comment: @campa Thank you very much Campa, "title" is just a case, could you give me an example of using \pardox or minipage?

Comment: @campa, perfect, this is what I want, really appreciate your help very much Campa.

Comment: @campa Moreover, could you tell me how to make the underline lengths of all lines same, since I noticed that the underline length of the last line varies according to the content of the sentence and it is not centered, how to fix this and make all the underline length same and the words of the last line centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the text into a `minipage` or a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

With \verb+minipage+:
\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}
\uline{This a very long title just for demonstration so how to make it  wrap automatically according to the fixed width}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

With \verb+\parbox+:
\parbox[t]{200pt}{%
\uline{This a very long title just for demonstration so how to make it  wrap automatically according to the fixed width}}

\end{document}
```

[image]